# Google Drive trash Clear Using Php not works

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to clear Trash using php and drive api v3. Code excutes with no error but trash in drive is not deleted. Here is my code please help me to fix this. Thanks For your time.

```
if($_POST['trash']) { 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/trash?key='.$token.'");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
};
```

Comment: Key is used for an API key not an access token if you want to pass an access token in the query string you would use ?access_token= . $token.    Please edit your question and include the code that creates the token.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for your comment. In my proposal, I proposed to use the access token as the request header instead of the query parameter. I know that in the current stage, the query parameter of `access_token` can be used for the method of "Files: emptyTrash" in Drive API. Can I ask you about the issue in my proposal? I would like to study from this question.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are Using to create this token.   Its better to pass it as an authorization header Google is going away from passing the access token in the query string.   Have you done a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22trashed%22%7D&apix=true) to check the trashed status of the current user?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - this question is in no way related to cURL itself, even if you are using it

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and current situation as follows.

- You want to use "Files: emptyTrash" in Drive API v3 using curl of php.
- Your access token of `$token` can be used for using this API.

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/trash?key='.$token.'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

#### To:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/trash");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

#### Note:

- At "Files: emptyTrash", no values are returned.
- If `$token` in your script is the API key which is not the access token, please retrieve the access token and use it. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: emptyTrash](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/emptyTrash)

Comment: I tried that but it still return same. Nothing is deleted from trash.

Comment: @xcoders Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, when the correct access token is used for the modified script, I can confirm that the script works. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. So, when `echo curl_error($ch);` is put before `curl_close($ch);`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @xcoders Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this again. In your case, `if($_POST['trash']) { ` is `true`? And `$token` is the valid access token for using "Files: emptyTrash" in Drive API?

Comment: Yes access token is valid. `if($_POST['trash']) ` is not empty and is true.

Comment: @xcoders Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested your script, I can confirm that the same issue occurred. The error of `Illegal characters found in URL` occurred. And when I tested the modified script, I could confirm that the trash box became empty with no error. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In your situation, are you testing the simple script of the modified script? If you were testing your script including other script, can you test it using the simple script? How about this?

Comment: @xcoders From your replying, it seems that your access token is valid for using the API. So as a simple test method, when you run the following curl command using your access token, what result will you obtain? `curl -X DELETE -H 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/trash'` In my environment, when the access token is correct for using this API, when this curl command is run, the trash box became empty.